# Something is missing in my querie, and i feel burned

Tags: oracle

I have this complicated querie and I have to fix it, at the moment I think there is an error in the where, something will be missing there, but I am not sure, that's why I ask you for help from the powerful people of stackoverflow.

If you want it is good and without errors, that means that the error is in the data entry, and that would have an easier solution.

I definitely have to improve in consultations.

Query:

```
SELECT
  t.TICKET,
  t.TIPOOPERACION,
  o.DESCRIPCION_CAS AS DESCOPCAS,
  o.DESCRIPCION_CAT AS DESCOPCAT,
  o.DESCRIPCION_EN AS DESCOPEN,
  ca.ORDEN,
  t.APLORIGEN,
  t.FECHAALTA,
  t.FECHACADUCIDAD,
  t.ESTADO,
  t.OFICINA,
  t.CONTRATO,
  t.VISIBILIDAD,
  t.VISIBLECLI,
  t.RESPONSABLE,
  t.USUARIOMOD,
  t.CANAL,
  t.IDPART,
  t.DATOS,
  t.FECHAMODIFICACION,
  t.COMENTARIOS,
  t.PEA,
  t.PARAMETROSPEA,
  t.URL,
  ca.DESCRIPCION_CAS AS descCategoriaCas,
  ca.DESCRIPCION_CAT AS descCategoriaCat,
  ca.DESCRIPCION_EN AS descCategoriaEn,
  t.categoria,
  o.IMAGEN,
  t.NUM_MENSAJE,
  NVL2(t.FECHAMODIFICACION, 'S', 'N') AS LEIDO,
  t.COD_VISUALIZACION,
  t.INFO_VARIABLE,
  TRUNC(
    (
      TO_DATE(t.FECHACADUCIDAD, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
    )
  ) AS DIAS_CADUCIDAD,
  t.ID_APLICACION,
  t.HORA_CADUCIDAD,
  t.DATOS_VISUALIZACION,
  t.IMPORTE,
  t.DIVISA,
  o.OPERATIVA,
  t.LISTA_ID_GDD AS listaiddocumentos,
  t.REF_AGRUPADORA_GDD,
  T.FECHA_INICIO AS FECHAINICIO,
  TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(
      CONCAT(t.FECHACADUCIDAD, ' '),
      DECODE (t.HORA_CADUCIDAD, NULL, '23:59', t.HORA_CADUCIDAD)
    ),
    'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI'
  ) AS FECHACADUCIDADCOMPLETA,
  t.PREGUNTA_SECRETA,
  t.OPERACION_BLOQUEADA,
  t.FECHA_BLOQUEO,
  o.MINUTOS_BLOQUEO,
  t.NUMERO_EMPLEADO,
  t.NUMERO_EMPLEADO_MOD,
  t.TIPO_PERSONA,
  t.CONSOLIDA_SIN_FIRMA AS CONSOLIDARSINFIRMA,
  o.CONSOLIDAR_SIN_FIRMA AS PUEDECONSOLIDADSINFIRMA,
  o.CONSOLIDAR_CON_ERROR_FIRMA as puedeConsolidarErrorFirma,
  t.LISTA_DOC_NO_DEMORABLE AS listaDocNoDemorable,
  t.DEMORA,
  t.SUBCANAL,
  t.MONITORING_DATOS,
  (
    SELECT
      LITERAL_MOTIVO
    FROM
      TDE_MOTIVOS_ELIMINAR M
      INNER JOIN TDE_TAREAS T ON T.ID_MOTIVO_ELIMINAR = M.ID_MOTIVO
    WHERE
      TICKET = ?
  ) as motivoEliminar,
  DECODE(
    (
      SELECT
        ESTADO
      FROM
        TDE_TAREAS
      WHERE
        TICKET = ?
    ),
    4,
    'S',
    'N'
  ) AS puedeFirmar,
  t.PNOW,
  t.POFI,
  t.PARAMETROS_POFI as parametrosPOfi,
  t.LITERAL_AGRUPACION,
  DECODE (t.TICKET_ANIDADO, NULL, 'N', 'S') AS STOPANIDADO,
  t.TIPOANIDAMIENTO,
  t.TICKET_PADRE AS ticketPadre,
  t.NUEVO_CIRCUITO as nuevoCircuito,
  t.ticket_anidado as ticketAnidado,
  (
    DECODE (t.TIENE_HIJOS, NULL, 'N', t.TIENE_HIJOS)
  ) AS tieneHijos,
  o.tipoanulacion AS tipoAnulacion,
  o.eliminable,
  t.VISIBILIDAD_PERSONA AS visibilidadPer
FROM
  tde_tareas t,
  tde_operaciones o,
  tde_categoria ca
WHERE
  AND o.tipooperacion = t.tipooperacion
  AND o.categoria = t.categoria
  AND ca.categoria = t.categoria
```

This is the error:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Please post in English.

Comment: And based on the error message you are using oracle, not mysql or ms sql server. Pls pay attention how you tag your questions!

Comment: @Shadow thanks, i didn't know i was using oracle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: "_I think there is an error_" when you have "_This is the error: ORA-00936: missing expression_", means you really have an error. However, did you write all that SQL without executing it even once during the process? Take smaller steps, write a smaller query. Execute. Add _some_ functionality. Execute. Etc.

Comment: 1) ANSI-92 explicit `JOIN` syntax has been around for ***three decades***, you should be using that, not implicit joins with `,`. 2). Basic debugging is to delete the whole SELECT clause and see if the joins work, then add one expression at a time to the SELECT clause until one breaks it. 3). `DECODE` is a function and should not have a space after it; `DECODE(`, not `DECODE (`.  4). Starting a `WHERE` clause with `AND` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
WHERE
  AND o.tipooperacion = t.tipooperacion
```

Remove `AND` (or add some condition behind `WHERE`, if there is any you - possibly - missed or deleted).

Comment: Thank you guys, i think i seeing it, and sry for making this very poor explained question, the thing is im a student and well i want to be better, the teacher told me to make it easy and make diferent queries but im stubborn and i wanted to make only one. 

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ClaudiuFlorinOneata Listen to your teacher, readability, testability, and maintainability matter. You ***do not*** know better than your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't joined the tables in the **FROM**

```
FROM
  tde_tareas t
  join tde_operaciones o
  on o.tipooperacion = t.tipooperacion AND o.categoria = t.categoria
  join tde_categoria ca on ca.categoria = t.categoria;
```

Comment: Because the OP is using massively outdated `,` syntax for the joins.  Using this (ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax) would make the bad WHERE clause (started with AND) less likely to happen and significantly easier to spot.

Comment: @MatBailie I see now the it was the `and` in the where which was the problem, which I removed in making the joins. Should I remove this answer?

Comment: No, it actively changes the OP's query, in a sensible way, to both improve it and correct the error.